# Spring MVC: RequestMapping not working, no URL paths identified

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I've googled this problem, but no one seem so the have exactly the same problem as me.

I'm trying to setup a simple Spring MVC application. These are the relevant files:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">

...

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyApp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

myapp-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <mvc:annotation-driven/>
        <context:component-scan base-package="myapp.gui"/>

        <bean class= "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
        </bean>     
</beans>
```

HomeController.java

```
@Controller
public class HomeController 
{
    @RequestMapping({"/"})
    public String showHomePage(Map<String,Object> model)
    {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

I have a home.jsp in WEB-INF\views. The problem is my app isn't returning a home page. I just get a 404 and although Spring is finding my controller (the log says so) it's giving the error:  no URL paths identified.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Paul

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with /app/* as the servlet mapping url and /home as the RequestMapping. Then try accessing it with /app/home. There are certain issues with mapping /* - once you get the rest of the mapping working with /app - we can look at removing the /app

Comment: Hi gkamal, I had the same issue.. so after adding app it is working .. can u tell how to remove app now..?

Answer (score 0):

I once wanted to complete a spring MVC project with rest URLs and I too could not find any really useful resources.  I did post an article on my blog, but have since removed the blog.  Here is an extract from the post:

I am using:

- NetBeans 6.9.1
- Spring Framework 3.0.2 RELEASE (including JSTL)
- JAVA JDK 6
- GlassFish Server 3

1. - Start new NetBeans project
   - choose Java Web – Web Application
   - Click Next >
   - Enter Project Name "restMVC" and choose the project location
   - Click Next >
   - Choose GlassFish Server 3 – select Java EE 6 Web
   - Click Next >
   - Check Spring Web MVC – click Configuration tab and change Dispatcher Name to "restMVC" and Dispatcher Mapping to "/"
   - Click Finish
2. Open `restMVC-servlet.xml` – we want to have the servlet search for the `@Controller` annotation within classes within a specific package, to do that we need to insert a context:component-scan into the file which means we also need to add the schemeLocation as follows:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xsi:schemaLocation="

     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd

     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="restMVC.web"/>
   ...
   ```

   Of course, we haven’t created the package yet, so let’s do that.
3. - Right click on "Source Packages"
   - Go to New
   - Click Java Package
   - Enter the Package Name `restMVC.web`
4. Now we can create our first controller –

   - Right click on the new restMVC.web package
   - Go to New
   - Click Java class
   - Enter the Class Name `myController`
5. Next add the `@Controller` annotation, then right click – fix imports:

   ```java
   package restMVC.web;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

   @Controller
   public class myController {
   }
   ```
6. Now we can add some request mapping URIs, remember we now have many different options for mapping using the @RequestMapping annotation, so be sure to review the Spring Docs.

   ```java
   package restMVC.web;

   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
   import org.springframework.ui.Model;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

   @Controller
   public class myController {
       @RequestMapping("/test")
       public String getTests(Model model) {
           List tests = new ArrayList();
           tests.add("<a href=\"test/1\">test 1</a>");
           tests.add("<a href=\"test/2\">test 2</a>");
           model.addAttribute("tests", tests);
           return "tests";
       }
       @RequestMapping("/test/{testId}")
       public String getTest(@PathVariable String testId, Model model) {
           List tests = new ArrayList();
           tests.add("test " + testId);
           model.addAttribute("tests", tests);
           return "tests";
       }
   }
   ```
7. We need to create a view for `tests.jsp`. This is created by taking the String that is returned from the `getTests` and `getTest` methods ("tests") and using the viewResolver in the `restMVC-servlet.xml` appending `.jsp` – more on that to come.

   - Right click on (projects view) restMVC -> Web Pages -> WEB-INF -> jsp folder
   - Click New
   - Click JSP..
   - Enter File Name "tests"
8. Edit `tests.jsp`. Enter the following at the top of the page:

   ```jsp
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
   ```

   And then this within the body element:

   ```jsp
   <table>
     <c:forEach var="test" items="${tests}">
       <tr>
         <td>${test}</td>
       </tr>
     </c:forEach>
   </table>
   ```
9. Finally we need to make sure the viewResolver is in `restMVC-servlet.xml`. The complete file should look like:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
     <context:component-scan base-package="restMVC.web"/>
     <bean id="viewResolver"
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
       p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
       p:suffix=".jsp" />
   </beans>
   ```
10. You might want to edit `redirect.jsp` so it redirects to `/test`.
11. Now click "Run Main Project"